# Is it possible to run an ARM64 vagrant instance on the x86_64 host

Tags: linux, vagrant, qemu, vagrantfile, libvirt

I'm trying to run an ARM64 Ubuntu VM on an x86_64 host with vagrant for development purposes. I searched the vagrant box on their website only found this one:

https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search?provider=libvirt&q=arm64&sort=downloads&utf8=%E2%9C%93

However, I failed to bring that VM up (using `vagrant up --provider libvirt`) as it seems using the `qemu-system-x86_64` as the simulator instead of the `qemu-system-aarch64`. The vagrantfile I used：

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "MalibuKoKo/ubuntu-18.04.3-server-arm64-raspberry-4"
  config.vm.define "ubuntu18.04-aarch64"
  config.vm.provider :libvirt do |libvirt|
    libvirt.machine_arch = "aarch64"
    libvirt.uri = 'qemu:///system'
    libvirt.emulator_path = "/usr/bin/qemu-system-aarch64"
  end
end
```

Any suggestion how to bring it up? Thanks

Comment: Hey, have you ever figured it out?

Comment: @minexew no....